# Saving large quantity of data without slowing a thread down

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, performance, serialization

I need to save a trace of a video system for later inspection-replay on a Windows machine.

The frame generation is done in a thread and I'd like to save the frames at the end of the processing function, e.g.

```
void generate_video_frame() {

    ....

    save_frame(frame);
}
```

To avoid slowing the generation thread down `save_frame` must accomplish this as quickly as possible. The ultimate goal is to have a disk-saved trace of the video.

Each frame can be quite big (even 20-30 MB) so I can't just store everything in RAM since I'll eventually fill it up completely.

I thought of two solutions:

- Filling a queue of frames and using another thread to empty it and flush it to disk (so the main thread won't be affected). This might eventually also fill up the RAM if the flush-to-disk thread is slower (as I expect)
- Use a [mapped file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28VS.85%29.aspx) and write each frame as soon as I can

Is there a better approach? If not, what are the downsides/caveats I should be aware of?

Comment: write to file asynchronous

Comment: @RbMm *write to file asynchronous*  One problem with that is error handling - how do you handle an IO error cleanly when there are 50 pending IO requests queued up for an async write?  Another is managing the data buffers which likely have to be left untouched until the async write completes.  It's probably a lot easier to just put the frame objects into a queue for a writer thread, as the OP suggests.

Comment: *Each frame can be quite big (even 20-30 MB) so I can't just store everything in RAM since I'll eventually fill it up completely.*  Limit the queue size - once the queue reaches a certain size, have the producer threads block until the queue size drops when trying to add to the queue.  Yes, it will slow down frame generation, but ultimately your frame generation rate is limited to how fast you can write to disk anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - of course handle. how many pending io request exist not play role here at all

Comment: @RbMm *how many pending io request exist not play role here at all* Of course the number of pending IO requests play a role.  The memory buffers holding the data to be written can't be reused for another purpose until the asynchronous write has completed. The buffers need to be kept and tracked, and the OP has already stated memory usage is a consideration.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - of course buffers must have reference counting and not be reused until io complete. but in any case it can not be reused until io complete. put frames to queue ? and what next ? again memory can not be reused until you write it to disk. so until io complete. so what ?

Comment: *put the frame objects into a queue for a writer thread* - what is this change ? bufferes must be valid until write complete in any case. what you gain if delegate this task to separate thread, which you want use synchronous io ? you think this will be faster ? of course no. synchronous io - this is asynchronous io after which we wait in place. less memory usage ? no. can free bufferes from another thread, before write complete ? again can not. this is error. so what we gain with this compare just asynchronous io ?

Comment: @RbMm What you gain is simplicity, reliability, and ease of error handling.  What are you going to use to track the IO buffers for pending asynchronous writes?  Async IO is a waste of code here - it isn't going to be any faster, it needlessly complicates error handling, and if there is any order requirement on the data written to the output file it makes determining where to put the data into the file hopelessly complex - especially if the amount of data written to the file by a frame isn't known until the data is actually written.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - what is more simply and easy - relative. *reliability* - asynchronous io not less reliable that something else. error handling - not view any problems. *What are you going to use to track the IO buffers for pending asynchronous writes?*  - every asynchronous io have context object - pointer to `OVERLAPPED` or `IO_STTUS_BLOCK` which we got back when io complete. in this object we can have pointers to buffer used in io, pointer to object which encapsulate file handle (to where we write) and all another needed data. so really no any problem if know how correct use asynchronous io

Comment: *and if there is any order requirement on the data written to the output file it makes determining where to put the data into the file hopelessly complex* -when we use asynchronous io - we always must direct set file offset to where write.. again - no any problems here. if have enough knowledge and experience in this

Comment: @RbMm It seems asynchronous IO is your [hammer, and every problem is therefore a nail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).  *we always must direct set file offset to where write.. again - no any problems here.*  Really?  How do you know what the OP's `save_frame()` does?  You **don't**, so you can't say you know in this case where to write in the output file.

Comment: @AndrewHenle- it is possible solution here. nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends. What is the source of your frames? Do they come from a real-time source, i.e., a camera, and are then processed in some way? Or are they simply generated from any type of data (and there is no real-time pressure from a data source).

Your question somehow suggests the latter. If this is the case, I suggest to indeed run creation and write to disk in different threads. Actually, there could be even more to it, you might not only have two tasks but three:

1. Generation of image data
2. Encoding of video data
3. Writing video data to disk

The first does not seem to be your bottleneck, so I suggest running this and filling up a queue until you run above a certain limit of the queue (to avoid running out of RAM) and just wait then.

The second, encoding, compresses your data, at the expense of processing time. Once the images are there, this can be done independently from generation. There's a lot of choice here (from lossless codecs to lossy codecs with different qualities), but it's often worth doing this. After this, you can only store the compressed data in RAM, reducing your RAM usage. On the other hand, this of course costs some processing power and (assuming it's multi-threaded already) might slow your data creation down. So here, you can balance data size vs. generation speed for the best possible balance.

Finally, writing to disk. If you write uncompressed data, this is a lot. If it's compressed, not as much. Since often, writing to disk is kind of slow, writing less data helps, of course. Also, writing larger chunks of data is more efficient than writing small amounts of data. So collecting a couple of frames and writing them at once might save you time.

There's a lot of screws here where you can optimize. Your goal seems to be to have the overall system as fast as possible. The question usually is when to invest the work to do that. If whatever you are developing is working and it is just about performance, you might go for it. If you are just concerned about this, but what you want to be doing in the end is not done yet, I always suggest to make it run first and make it fast later.